# Auto Layout and "Hide bottom bar when pushed"

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, autolayout

My app's (simplified) structure is this:

`UITabBarController` with one `UINavigationController` holding a `UITableViewController` as root view controller.

when tapping one of the table view controller cells, I push a regular `UIViewController` (lets call it VC) end hiding the bottom tab bar. (using the "Hide bottom bar when pushed" flag)

In storyboard I added a regular `UIView` subclass to VC that look like a bottom bar, and I use Auto Layout to pin it to the bottom of the VC view.

**The problem**
when I push VC it takes a second for this view to pin to the bottom, it looks like auto layout pin it to the bottom as if the tab bar is not hidden and after a sec it recognise that the tab bar is hidden and moves it to the real bottom of the view.

I know its not the best explanation, so I added a [very simple project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8648042F7CE0575!107&authkey=!AN_CMRRlUlovrms&ithint=file%2Czip) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I think you're not using the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property in the intended way (look at that method in the docs). It's supposed to be for hiding the tool bar that a navigation controller can present, not the tab bar.

Comment: hi @rdelmar so what is the proper way to hide the tab bar when pushed? this supposed to be a very common thing to do i believe.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The problem is with this specific constraint which is between the view and the top of the bottom layout guide.

[image]

Select the constraint and edit its "Second Item" property

[image]

Here you need to choose bottom

[image]

Once you have that, the pink view is not influenced by layout guide anymore. The layout guide seem to acknowledge that the tab bar is hidden only after the root view of the pushed view controller is in the bounds of main screen and this happens only when the animation is finished.

And that is the reason the view hierarchy needs to be laid out again which causes the unwanted animation.

Comment: When autolayout will not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334285/replacing-tabbar-with-toolbar-in-storyboard/30283470#30283496

Comment: @AnthonyM I ran into that problem as well. I ended up editing the storyboard's source by hand so that I could change the constraint's item to use bottom layout guide.bottom.

Comment: @AnthonyM it's a bit hidden in Xcode 7 but it's there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33432500/125407

Comment: just wondering how you managed to edit storyboard source by hand so that you could change the constraint's item to use bottom layout guide.bottom?   I've been stuck on this for sometime now and don't understand why I can't just select bottom in storyboard anymore?

Answer (score 32):

The accepted answer did not work for me (the option was not available). However I have found another solution. (based on [Hide Bottom Bar When Pushed through Autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411719/hide-bottom-bar-when-pushed-through-autolayout))

Select booth the view and the object to align (in my case btnShare) and add a new alignment constraint (Bottom Edges).

[image]
[image]

Comment: This did not work for me, I still get 1s of white space displayed when pushing ViewController.

Comment: Super...Very useful

Answer (score 14):

Hi In storyboard select Tab bar (Is Tab Bar Controller Scene > Tab Bar Controller > Tab Bar ), in the attribute inspector, uncheck Translucent box. This action fix your problem. (But there are many things, "Hide bottom bar when pushed" is to toolbar).

Comment: but now the tab bar is visible when I push VC, I need it to be hidden.

Comment: At least, in the example project you have shared (AutoLayoutTest), if you only uncheck translucent property in the tab bar, the tab bar disappear when you push and the violet view appear in its place. (Test you own project)

Comment: worked for me, but i m looking for any future bug it may cause.

Answer (score 6):

Select your "Navigation Controller" and in "Attribute Inspector" remove the checkmark from "Under Bottom Bars".

Answer (score 6):

IF you can't select bottomlayoutguide bottom in your Xcode 7+

[image: like there]
just do the following:
open your storyboard in source code editor

[image: open in editor]
search your controller's identifier

[image: search in source file]
find `<layoutGuides>`, type `<bottom>`, copy it id

[image: find layoutGuides]
search by id
change attribute from top to bottom

[image: find and replace]
enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

In the storyboard, Go to the View Controller that you want to hide the tab bar, click on *Attribute Inspector* and select *Hide bottom bar when pushed*. Check image bellow.

[image: storyboard example]

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Set "Hide bottom bar on push" on the view controller, that should not show the tab bar. Don't set it on the tab bar controller, the navigation controller or on the parent view controller of your controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the tab bar to be hidden, you can add this code to your controller,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

You will also have to put that code (but passing NO) into the controller where you want the tab bar to be visible. You should also deselect the "Hide bottom bar when pushed" box in IB.

**After Edit:**

You'll get a better animation if, in the first controller, you animate the alpha value of the non-hidden tab bar from 0 to 1 over a short time. This looks good if you go back with the back button. If you want to use the swipe back, you would have to do something more complicated involving the interactivePopGestureRecognizer.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that you see the disappearing / appearing of the tab bar. especially when using the swipe back gesture.

Comment: @Eyal, I edited my answer to show ways to improve the animation.

Comment: im not comfortable with this kind of solution, hiding/showing the tab bar on viewWillAppear/viewWillDisapear is a bit risky i think. it seems that "hide bottom bar" works great without auto layout, so I wonder if there is something to do with the auto layout configuration.

Comment: @Eyal, what's wrong with Onik IV's solution? I don't see the tab bar either when I uncheck the translucent property for the tab bar (and hide's bottom bar on push is still checked).

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 5.0;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set UINavigationBar Translucent with NO.

like this: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Answer (score 0):

Try pinning bottom of your view to bottom of superview and not bottom-layout