# Toolbar incorrectly positioned during push animation with hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have an App using a Tabbar for basic Navigation. From one of the screens of the Tabbar I want to enter another one that shows a toolbar instead of the Tabbar and a back navigation item on the top.

What is the best way to do this? If I use "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" (aka hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) and add a Toolbar to the screen I can see an animation removing the Tabbar before the Toolbar is placed at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: trying to figure this myself. Did you sort it out ? Its bounty time !!

Comment: Is this the effect you're looking for: http://i.imgur.com/eACSkMS.gif ?

Comment: Thats the effect I want, I was about to create a gif of the problem. But my solution gives the effect you show.

Comment: @DogCoffee I came up with a pure storyboard solution to this, I'll write up an answer and post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution for `UITableViewController` with toolbar (requires code)

Using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19625773/834998), I was able to achieve the same effect, but with the toolbar at the bottom of a table view.

Add this to your table view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

**Important note**: placing these calls in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` instead of `viewDidLoad` makes this easier to handle, as it will work reliably even for multiple pushes and pops of the same view controller, and you won't have to clean up after it in the previous view controller.

And configure it like this in the storyboard:

[image]

Also, enable **Hides bottom bar when pushed** in the storyboard, or in your code, for the view controller being pushed.

Then you can add toolbar buttons to the toolbar in the storyboard.

Build and run, and you get this effect:

[image]

[Here's a complete sample project demonstrating this](http://cl.ly/1g3h2r3N3N2o).

Comment: I tried this but not working with my app, still getting the animation of the toolbar up on the second VC.

Comment: @DogCoffee try looking at the sample project and comparing the settings. I created it from the default template and only changed the things listed here.

Comment: What are you using to create your GIF's ? My created GIFs aint great.

Comment: I did it like that, the only difference is that I chose to use self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false) to avoid showing the animation to the user

Comment: Still an issue on 10.2 Xcode 8.2.1. Only seems to happen with Swift projects for me. This is the only solution still working, most of the other solutions fail to have any effect or solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Problem Example

[image]

Here is my solution,

In the **first view** controller that has the **tabbar** do this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "someSegue" {
        if let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as? InfoTableViewController {
            secondVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        }
    }
}
```

I also needed this, as my **toolbar** would re appear in the first VC.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true
}
```

To stop the fade up animation of the **toolbar**, so its just there i used this in the **second VC**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pure storyboard solution

If you're referring to the issue of the toolbar appearing above the tab bar during the push transition animation, I was able to fix this by adjusting the auto layout constraints on the toolbar in the storyboard (add it manually to your view controller; see my other answer if you're using a `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController` and can't do this):

Add a constraint to set the distance to the bottom layout guide to zero:

[image]

Double click that constraint to edit it, and set the **first item** to **Bottom** (it will be **Top** by default).

[image]

All done! This will result in an effect like this:

[image]

[Here's my sample project](http://cl.ly/0c3N1Z1Q1w15) that demonstrates this working as expected. Note that I didn't change any of the code, everything is in the storyboard.

Comment: I have seen this answer, but if you use a UITableViewController, you cannot add constraints to the toolBar (when you show it in interface builder)... well I couldnt anyway.

Comment: @DogCoffee I couldn't find a way to do this with constraints either, but it's still doable, similarly to your answer, but avoiding cleanup in the source view controller (see my second answer).

Comment: I posted my first answer (and will leave it separate) because the question doesn't mention a table view being used, and is tagged `storyboard`, so I think a storyboard solution could be more convenient for the asker than the alternate one.

Comment: Xcode 7 doesn't allow you to change Top to Bottom for Bottom Layout Guide anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 7, the pure Storyboard solution doesn't work anymore because Xcode wouldn't let you assign the `Bottom` attribute to the Bottom Layout Guide anymore.

For my project, I used the following setup:

- A `UITabBarController` as initial view controller, going into a
- `UINavigationController`, with root vc set to...
- `UIRegularViewController`, which should behave normally, but spawn a...
- `UISpecialViewController`, which should hide the tab bar and instead display a toolbar. Also, it should hide the status bar, the navigation bar and the tool bar on tap.

Here is what I did to achieve this:

**In the storyboard**

`UITabBarController`: set Tab Bar Translucency to **NO**

`UISpecialViewController`: Set *Simulated Metrics* like so

- Status Bar: None
- Top Bar: Opaque Nav Bar
- Bottom Bar: Opaque Toolbar

Set *Extended Edges* like this:

- Under Top Bars: NO
- Under Bottom Bars: YES
- Under Opaque Bars: YES

Do **not** drag a UIToolBar into `UISpecialViewController` !

**In the Implementations**

```
// in UISpecialViewController.m
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = NO;
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden;
}
```

Here is the [Demo Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5896473/navtest.zip).

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact, UIKit has already configured how Toolbar and Tabbar change in the page switching animation.

I also have this situation with you today, and the final solution surprised me.

For example, page A to page B, page A displays Tabbar, not Toolbar, page B does not display Toolbar, and does not display Tabbar.

At this time, B needs to set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to true, which is necessary.

Then, in the declaration cycle of the two ViewControllers, in the viewWillDisappear of A and the viewWillAppear of B, if you set the navigation controller setToolbarHidden, this animation problem will occur.

**If you set it in viewDidDisappear of A and viewDidAppear of B, the problem is solved. Although the toolbar will have a delayed animation, it is always better than the wrong animation.**

Finally add:
The order of A and B life cycle function calls is:

1. A - viewWillDisappear
2. B - viewWillAppear
3. A - viewDidDisappear
4. B - viewDidAppear

These four methods are interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 12.4 iOS 14.4

for those who struggle with this issue and try solutions above with no luck.

let's say A is with tabBar only, B is only showing toolbar

remember to set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` in B's init

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

implement these below in B. (no need to do anything in A)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

that's it!!

p.s. if you want to remove the toolbar animation from bottom up then add this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    navigationController?.toolbar.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "position")
}
```